# A function is called twice in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, function, scroll

I have a function that is called twice and I don't know what to do.

This is the code that is called when I press an input button on a WebBrowser:

```
Private Sub WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) _
Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted

    Document = sender.Document
    AddHandler Document.Click, New HtmlElementEventHandler(AddressOf Document_Click)

End Sub

Private Sub Document_Click(sender As Object, e As HtmlElementEventArgs)

    Select Case Document.ActiveElement.Id.ToLower
        Case "global" : prueba()
        Case Else
    End Select

End Sub
```

If you want to see the function called `prueba()` here it is: http://pastebin.com/Fi5LLX2N

I have a video where I show it, but the annotations are in Spanish: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OCJXk3qJwVA

---

Well I have another problem with my function, as you can see, on the bottom I have put this:

```
Else
     MsgBox("Este ModPack ya lo tienes instalado!")
End If
```

But it doesn't work. :(

Comment: oke. not realy sure what you are asking.

Comment: Just to clarify, it's your function `prueba()` that is being called twice? Also, it likely isn't too critical, but it might help to give us an English definition of that word.

Comment: Yes, it is the function that is called twice. Prueba in English means "test".

Comment: How many frames exist in the document you're loading?

Comment: What do you mean with the word Frames?

Comment: Frames are standard HTML feature.  Pay attention to e.Url in your event handler to know when you got the last frame.

Comment: I didn't found what are you mean, sorry guys I'm very newbie. Can you check it for me: http://ikillcraft.a0001.net/modpacks.php?pass=test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

PS: It's written on the fly maybe can have some syntax error.

```
Private Sub WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) _
Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted

    Document = sender.Document
    try : removehandler Document.Click, addressof(Document_Click): catch :   end try
    AddHandler Document.Click, New HtmlElementEventHandler(AddressOf Document_Click)

End Sub
```

Comment: I've misstyped an "s" -> adressof

Answer (score 0):

My immediate reaction is a sticky mouse button, but really it's likely due to the web page you are loading having multiple pages being loaded, thus adding the duplicate event handler.  Put a breakpoint on this line of code:

```
AddHandler Document.Click, New HtmlElementEventHandler(AddressOf Document_Click)
```

You'll likely see it being hit twice.  Make sure to only wire up one HtmlElementEventHandler to avoid the double firing of the click event handler.  You can check e.Url for a match before wiring up as a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

in vb.net there is no need to define onclick in html for button because it is handled automatically.so if you are doing this then the click event will fire twise.